# How to hide a content on stacked Bar Chart below X - Axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have drawn a horizontal stacked bar chart using d3 js in a box frame on jsp page. But the stack bar chart is huge i.e. SVG content is so big that all the bars of the stacked bar chart does not fit in the box and I have to put auto overflow in the box element, so that when I scroll I can see the hidden bars.

So I have a problem over here.
If the number of bars in stacked bar chart is so big that all does not fit in the box at one go then X- Axis is not visible and I have to scroll all the way down to see the values on X-Axis.

What I want to do is keep my X-Axis just above the bottom of the box frame  all the time and hide the content on the stacked bar chart below X -Axis.

I can manage the position of X-Axis make it visible all the time(even on scroll). I need help in hiding the content of of the stacked bar chart below the X-Axis.
This is how I changed the X-Axis position, although this wont help when scroll is performed.

`svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - 15) + ')')
        .call(xAxis);`

I cant give the actual code, but I have tried to create my requirement on jsfiddle.

This what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/tusharkale52/ztzcsms5/

You can see that the X-Axis is after all the bars

This is what I want:
https://jsfiddle.net/tusharkale52/4qqec6hs/

X_Axis is in between and the bars and I want to hide everything below X-Axis(even Y-Axis line).

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found solution for the above question.
We need to follow a 3 step process.
1. Dynamically create a div tag and give it height and width and keep its top value such that the rectangular div tag appears at the bottom of the 'box' div.
The newly created div tag is inside the box div tag

2. We need to create another SVG element in the div tag created in step 1. and we need to append X-Axis to the newly created SVG element.

Write now I am just specifying the approach, so that anyone can use this if needed.
I will provide the proper solution in JSFiddle in sometime.

Thanks.